# Objective C @property accessors in custom class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessor

I have a custom NSObject called `MAAssignment`. It's basically a data type that has a number of `@properties` and one custom `init` method:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *totalPoints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *recievedPoints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *classAverage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *extraCredit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *notGraded;


- (id)initWithDate:(NSString *)date assignmentName:(NSString *)assignmentName totalPoints:(NSNumber *)totalPoints recievedPoints:(NSNumber *)recievedPoints classAverage:(NSString *)classAverage extraCredit:(NSNumber *)extraCredit notGraded:(NSNumber *)notGraded;
```

I create an instance of it in the `viewController`, hoping to populate the newly created item with some data... But I can't figure out how to access the variables of the object. I went `MAAssignment *assignment = [[MAAssignment alloc] init];`, then I tried `[assignment setDate]` or `assignment.date = ddate` but none of them seem to work.

Am I misunderstanding how the accessors for objects work?

Comment: What do you mean they don't work? How and where are you determining that they don't work?

Comment: You really need to provide more details for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please specify exactly what error message you get or exactly what does not work (please show code and describe expected results with the actual outcomes). As this question stands it should be closed for not providing enough information.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the very vague question. I realized that the dot notation, `assignment.[property]` lets me 'set' it's value...

Comment: The dot notation `assignment.date` can be used to both set and get a value. But you have still not said what your exact problem is other than "none of them seem to work". As an aside, you should replace the `(id)` in your designated initialiser with `(instancetype)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should place these variables in h. file
of MAAsignment

Comment: These look like they are in the .h.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding your question very well (where are you declaring this code? What's the full code of your MAAsiignment initialization example?), however I'll try to answer anyway.

Are you sure that the `@property` declarations are inside the @interface in `.h` and **not** inside `.m`? 
The `@interface` inside `.m` is a private class extensions, and allows you to declare **private** properties. To make them available outside, you need to put them inside the header (`.h`).

Please post more code to let us provide a more exhaustive answer.

Comment: This really make no attempt to answer the very vague question.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a data container object. It should work as described:

```
MAAssignment *anAssignment = [[MAAssignment alloc] init];
anAssignment.date = [NSDate date];
anAssignment.totalPoints = @(10);

NSLog(@"anAssignment.date = %@", anAssignment.date);
NSLog(@"anAssignment.totalPoints = %@", anAssignment.totalPoints);
```

Should work perfectly. Are you getting any warnings?